# React Native: Save local PDF file to users device

Tags: react-native, pdf, file-storage

I have a PDF stored in my assets folder in my react native projects. I would like to give the user the ability to download this PDF to their device. I currently have it displaying on screen, but I can't figure out how to download the asset to the users device. I've seen plenty of examples of how to download items using a URL but nothing for local assets. The application is being build out in React Native for both iOS and Android.

Comment: Look at this: https://github.com/vinzscam/react-native-file-viewer/issues/2

Comment: @Oleg that doesn't seem to work with iOS. Getting an error saying that the platform is not supported.

Comment: facing same issue, please advice